# Pronom qui renvoie un nom pas encore apparu

Tags: grammaire, pronoms

La phrase

> Comme il est le plus petit, le chat mange le rat.

est incorrecte, si ce que l'on voulait dire, c'était que le rat était petit, car, telle qu'elle est écrite, on comprend que "il" désigne "chat" et non "rat". Mais pourquoi est-ce le cas ?
Est-ce parce que "chat" est le premier nom masculin à suivre "il", ou parce que c'est le sujet de la phrase ?

Par exemple, est-ce que la phrase

> Parce qu'elle est très juteuse, Bob mange la pomme.

est correcte ? Il est clair que "elle" ne désigne pas "Bob", qui est le sujet de la phrase, mais le premier nom féminin qui le suit, soit "pomme". Quand je lis cette phrase, elle me semble incorrecte, mais je voudrais savoir si j'ai raison de le penser, et si oui, pourquoi ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparemment, il n'existe pas de règle et il incombe à la personne qui rédige le texte de faire en sorte qu'aucune ambigüité ne résulte. Ce principe est  énoncé de façon explicite dans la réponse d'un utilisateur au site [Projet Voltaire](https://www.question-orthographe.fr/question/referentiel-de-pronoms-personnels/) ; en particulier, il n'y a pas de règle de proximité.

> (Question) Il y a-t-il une règle sur l’emploi des pronoms par rapport au référent ? Ou bien est-ce une question du sens le plus canonique de la phrase ?
>
> Par exemple:
>
> Jean regarde Paul. Il lui dit bonjour. >> Ici « il » représente Jean et « lui » représente Paul, assez clairement.
> Jean regarde Paul. Stéphanie arrive et elle lui dit bonjour. >> Dans ce cas, est-ce que « lui » fait référence à Jean en tant que sujet, ou bien Paul par proximité ? Ou bien la phrase est cassée et il faut être spécifique ?
>
> Jean regarde Paul. Stéphanie arrive et il lui dit bonjour. >> Dans ce cas, « lui » représente certainement Stéphanie, mais « il » représente Jean ou Paul ?

> (Réponse, Tara)
> Il arrive bien souvent que les pronoms ne suffisent pas à reprendre clairement un nom.
> Justement, **l’utilisation judicieuse des pronoms est un critère de la maîtrise de la langue**. La personne qui écrit doit s’arranger pour que le sens soit clair et  donc que le référent ne fasse l’objet d’aucune hésitation (du moins généralement car l’ambiguïté peut être voulue dans certains cas évidemment).
> Jean regarde Paul. Stéphanie arrive et elle lui dit bonjour.
> Jean regarde Paul. Il lui dit bonjour.
> Jean regarde Paul. Stéphanie arrive et il lui dit bonjour.
> Dans ces phrases on ne peut savoir ce que reprennent les pronoms soulignés. Il n’y a pas de règle de proximité par exemple/
> Il faut donc expliciter d’une façon ou d’une autre.
> Par exemple (mais il y a bien d’autres façons d’éclaircir le message) :
> Jean regarde Paul à qui Stéphanie dit bonjour en entrant.
> Jean regarde Paul. Stéphanie arrive et dit bonjour à son frère (si l’un des deux est son frère)
> Jean regarde Paul et lui dit bonjour.
> Jean regarde Paul et dit bonjour à Stéphanie quand elle entre.
>
> On évitera cependant au premier, au second, à celui-ci ,qui sont lourds.

Les pronoms « ce dernier », « le dernier » sont cependant utiles pour éviter des ambigüités.

Le pronoms  « celui-là » et « celui-ci " sont aussi utiles pour différencier des antécédents.

> ([Wiktionnaire](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/celui-ci)) **celui-ci**    Celui dont on a parlé juste avant, par opposition au sujet ou le premier des deux du même type dans la phrase précédente.
> • "Cette mélancolique émotion me fait jeter en arrière un triste regard sur quelques années de ma vie, quoique ces années soient bien proches de celle-ci, et que cette vie ne soit pas bien longue encore." — (Alfred de Vigny, Servitude et grandeur militaires, 1835)

> ([Wiktionnaire](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/celui-l%C3%A0)) **celui-là**      La première personne ou chose des deux du même type dont on a parlées dans la phrase précédente.
>
> Quand on a nommé deux personnes ou deux choses et qu’on emploie ensuite les pronoms celui-ci et celui-là, celui-ci se rapporte au terme le plus proche, et celui-là au terme le plus éloigné.
> • Démocrite et Héraclite étaient de nature bien différente : celui-ci pleurait toujours, celui-là riait sans cesse. (celui-ci se rapporte à Héraclite et celui-là à Démocrite)

Selon ces directives on peut résoudre la difficulté de représentation utilisée comme exemple dans la première phrase de la façon suivante.

> Le rat étant plus petit que le chat, ce dernier le mange.

- Comme le rat est  plus petit que le chat , le chat le mange. (*une possibilité*)
- Considérant le chat et le rat, celui qui mange l'autre c'est le chat, celui-ci étant plus gros. (*autre possibilité*)
- Le chat mange le rat parce que ce dernier est plus petit.

(Il doit y avoir d'autres moyens d'arriver à la même fin.)

> Parce qu'elle est très juteuse, Bob mange la pomme.

Il ne me semble pas y avoir de problème dans cette phrase, l'antécédent étant clairement défini par le biais des genres.

Comment: Incidemment, dans la deuxième phrase, il ne s'agit que d'une antéposition alors qu'avec _comme_ pour la cause on doit normalement avoir la proposition en tête de phrase. S'il s'agissait d'un _raisin_ dans la deuxième, il serait bizarre de dire que la phrase marche avec la proposition postposée alors que non si elle est antéposée vu un trompe-l’œil...

Comment: @CrissyFroth-Seapickle: Je n'ai pas compris ta remarque, tu peux réexpliquer, s'il-te-plaît ?

Comment: _Bob mange le raisin parce qu'il est très juteux_ est une phrase qui fonctionne, donc je trouverais étrange qu'en plaçant en tête de phrase la subordonnée _parce qu'il est très juteux_, elle ne soit plus bonne. Dans la phrase avec le chat et le rat, la cause introduite avec _comme_ doit être en tête de phrase, l'usage le veut ainsi. C'était un commentaire non pas sur les pronoms mais sur la position des compléments, et il y a plusieurs règles là-dessus. Mais ce n'est pas déterminant, simplement une nuance. Le trompe l'oeil (_garden path_) c'est _il est juteux...Bob(x)... raisin_. @Plop